# Min cost edge deletions in tree to separate all leaves in a tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

This is from a larger problem, that I have boiled down to the following problem. Given a weighted tree with positive edge weights, and having k leaves. A leaf is a node which has exactly one adjacent node in the tree. I need to delete some edges from the tree so that the tree splits up into k components, with each component containing exactly one of the leaf nodes from the original tree. In other words, I need to delete edges so that all the leaves in the original tree are separated/disconnected from every other leaf of the original tree.

I need to do this in such a way that the sum of weights (cost) of the deleted edges is minimized. It is trivial to show that k-1 edges need to be deleted. So I need to minimize the sum of weights of these k-1 edges.

What is the optimal way to do this? Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think a greedy algorithm works here.

i.e. delete the lowest weight edge that generates a new component and repeat k-1 times.

Note that you have to be careful for a graph such as:

D<-A->B->C

If you delete B->C first, then deleting A->B does not generate a new component because B was not a leaf so does not need to be separated.

In other words, when selecting the lowest weight edge, do not include any edges that do not still lead to a leaf node.

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure if the greedy solution will indeed work. Also, is this optimal in terms of speed? This will take O(kn) time in the worst case, k being the number of leaves and n being the number of nodes. Run a DFS from each of k-1 leaves (any k-1 out of k), and find the minimum weight edge from it to any other leaves that are connected to it. Deletion of such an edge (on the path to some other leaf) will ensure that a new component is generated. Is there a faster way? Thanks again!

Comment: I think a fast solution would be to presort the edges in order of weight O(nlogn).  I think you can remove the bad edges by simply deleting any nodes which become new leaf nodes when you delete the lowest weight edge. To do this efficiently it may help to store parent pointers in each node.

Comment: If you delete the newly created leaves, they in turn might create new leaves. So to delete the bad edges, this deletion will need to go on till we don't have any leaves in the two newly generated components, that do not have a leaf node not present in the before the edge deletion. This basically is a DFS. Am I missing something?
By the way, the edges are not directed, so identifying the parent is  trivial.

Comment: Ah ok. Got it! We need to continue this deletion till we reach a node having more than two adjacent vertices (each of these paths will lead to one leaf present before the edge deletion). So there are atmost two traversals per edge: once when sorting all edges, and once when deleting. This should be O(nlogn). I'll try it out. Thanks!